# Python Удалить/добавить вложения в файл.eml

Tags: python, email

подскажите пожалуйста как отредактировать выгруженный файл формата eml
мне надо удалить вложения и вложить новые.
пробовала через decode но после того как файл прошел через decode и удалены вложения собрать обратно в eml не получилось

```
with open('name8.eml', 'rb') as fhdl: 
    raw_email = fhdl.read() 
parsed_eml = eml_parser.eml_parser.decode_email_b(raw_email)
parsed_eml['attachment']=[] 
parsed_eml.update
with open(path + "\\" + name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(parsed_eml)
```

выдает ошибку a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict' пробовала parsed_eml.encode() но аналогичный тип ошибки ругается на тип str

Comment: Добавьте пример кода, с которым у вас возникла проблема.

Comment: @insolor 

with open('name8.eml', 'rb') as fhdl:
    raw_email = fhdl.read()
parsed_eml = eml_parser.eml_parser.decode_email_b(raw_email)
parsed_eml['attachment']=[]
parsed_eml.update

with open(path + "\\" + name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(parsed_eml)
    
выдает ошибку  a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
пробовала parsed_eml.encode()
но аналогичный тип ошибки ругается на тип str

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: @insolor  добавила

Comment: Не пойдет. Вставьте код с отступами, выделите его, нажмите кнопку `{}` над редактором.

Comment: @insolor спасибо) поняла

Comment: Насколько я понял из документации, eml_parser не предназначен для редактирования eml файлов, только для их разбора. По идее можно использовать пакет email из стандартной библиотеки python, но я пока не нашел рабочих примеров.

Comment: @ insolor спасибо, пойду смотреть через email. Возможно подскажите, а есть способы конвертировать eml в msg формат (в msg понимаю как работать с вложениями, но конвертер в python не нашла  )?

Comment: Нет, не подскажу к сожалению.